# How Java class are loaded from the same directory?

Tags: java, jvm, load, classpath

How a java application launched with the classpath: "lib/*" will choose witch class to load if the lib directory contains several JAR with the same class?
The comportment will be the same every time? With different servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> The order in which the JAR files in a directory are enumerated in the expanded class path is not specified and may vary from platform to platform and even from moment to moment on the same machine. A well-constructed application should not depend upon any particular order. If a specific order is required, then the JAR files can be enumerated explicitly in the class path.

Comment: Do you know witch function does the expansion of the white-card?

Comment: @dev691 no. My guess is that it's some native code of the JVM.